# Including a row in the result of a SELECT for which the select didnt recover any data

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying write a query to retrieve the following data :

```
 TYPE     |    TOTAL   |  0_10 DAYS   |  10_20 DAYS   |  .......
  X             300         100            200           .......
  Y              0           0              0            .......
  Z             600         50             120           .......
```

I have to group all my entries  by type and count the number of entries of each type for each date range and add them up as a total. 
My problem is the need to display rows of zeros for the types for which I don't retrieve any data. Basically the type column always displays a fixed amount of types. So far I have tried using 'UNION ALL' but then the rows of zeros will always show. Here is my query :

```
SELECT TYPE             AS "ORDERS", 
       Count(*)         AS "TOTAL", 
       Nvl(Sum(CASE 
                 WHEN ( DATE_ORDER BETWEEN SYSDATE - 10 AND SYSDATE ) THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END), 0) AS "0_10_DAYS", 
       Nvl(Sum(CASE 
                 WHEN ( DATE_ORDER BETWEEN SYSDATE - 20 AND SYSDATE - 11 ) THEN 
                 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END), 0) AS "10_20_DAYS", 
       Nvl(Sum(CASE 
                 WHEN ( DATE_ORDER BETWEEN SYSDATE - 30 AND SYSDATE - 21 ) THEN 
                 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END), 0) AS "20_30_DAYS", 
       Nvl(Sum(CASE 
                 WHEN ( DATE_ORDER <= To_date(SYSDATE - 30) ) THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END), 0) AS "PLUS_30_DAYS" 
FROM   T_ORDERS 
WHERE  TYPE = 'X' 
        OR TYPE = 'Y' 
        OR TYPE = 'Z' 
GROUP  BY TYPE 
UNION ALL 
SELECT TYPE AS "ORDERS", 
       0    AS "TOTAL", 
       0    AS "0_10_DAYS", 
       0    AS "10_20_DAYS", 
       0    AS "20_30_DAYS", 
       0    AS "PLUS_30_DAYS" 
FROM   T_ORDERS 
WHERE  TYPE IS NOT NULL 
GROUP  BY TYPE;
```

I'm new to SQL so bear with me if any of the answers to questions on this topic solves mine but I can't seem to work it out. If something is unclear please write it in comment box.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Your table design is wrong. Instead of `TYPE | TOTAL | 0_10 DAYS | 10_20 DAYS | ...` you should have `TYPE | DAYS_NUM | VAL`. Then the problem will solve itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT TYPE              AS "ORDERS", 
       Count(DATE_ORDER) AS "TOTAL", 
       Nvl(Sum(CASE 
                 WHEN (DATE_ORDER BETWEEN SYSDATE - 10 AND SYSDATE) THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END), 0)  AS "0_10_DAYS", 
       Nvl(Sum(CASE 
                 WHEN (DATE_ORDER BETWEEN SYSDATE - 20 AND SYSDATE - 11) THEN 1
                 ELSE 0 
               END), 0)  AS "10_20_DAYS", 
       Nvl(Sum(CASE 
                 WHEN (DATE_ORDER BETWEEN SYSDATE - 30 AND SYSDATE - 21) THEN 1
                 ELSE 0 
               END), 0)  AS "20_30_DAYS", 
       Nvl(Sum(CASE 
                 WHEN (DATE_ORDER <= To_date(SYSDATE - 30)) THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END), 0)  AS "PLUS_30_DAYS" 
FROM   (SELECT TYPE, DATE_ORDER 
        FROM T_ORDERS 
        WHERE TYPE IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z')
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DECODE(LEVEL, 1,'X', 2,'Y', 3,'Z') TYPE, NULL DATE_ORDER 
        FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 
       ) SQ
GROUP  BY TYPE
```

Comment: This solution is not showing rows of zeros for every "TYPE" for which there aint data to retrieve.

Comment: @user2629578: Try now. (If you have a separate lookup table for TYPE values, you could use that instead of the SELECT DECODE ...).

Comment: Great! I think its working. Im going to test it a bit more. Could you give me a brief explanation of what u did? I get a bit lost with the DECODE & level. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @user2629578: It might be a little clearer if you run the `select decode(...` query on its own - like here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7863c/14 . The `decode` function is Oracle's shortened version of the CASE construct - documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm . The `connect by` clause is being used to generate a list of numbers from 1 to 3; this is an Oracle construct that can also be used to generate hierarchical queries - documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm .

Answer (score 0):

you can use an OUTER JOIN to achive the desired  result

```
with types
AS
(
  SELECT 'X' as t_name FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Y' as t_name FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Z' as t_name FROM dual
)
SELECT 
       types.t_name     AS "ORDERS", 
       SUM(CASE WHEN T_ORDERS.TYPE IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END )   AS "TOTAL", 
       Nvl(Sum(CASE 
                 WHEN ( DATE_ORDER BETWEEN SYSDATE - 10 AND SYSDATE ) THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END), 0) AS "0_10_DAYS", 
       Nvl(Sum(CASE 
                 WHEN ( DATE_ORDER BETWEEN SYSDATE - 20 AND SYSDATE - 11 ) THEN 
                 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END), 0) AS "10_20_DAYS", 
       Nvl(Sum(CASE 
                 WHEN ( DATE_ORDER BETWEEN SYSDATE - 30 AND SYSDATE - 21 ) THEN 
                 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END), 0) AS "20_30_DAYS", 
       Nvl(Sum(CASE 
                 WHEN ( DATE_ORDER <= To_date(SYSDATE - 30) ) THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END), 0) AS "PLUS_30_DAYS" 
FROM   
  types 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN T_ORDERS ON (types.t_name = T_ORDERS.TYPE ) 
GROUP  BY types.t_name
```

or if you already have all types in a TYPES table you can use this table instead of WITH

```
SELECT 
       types.t_name     AS "ORDERS", 
       SUM(CASE WHEN T_ORDERS.TYPE IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END )   AS "TOTAL",  
       Nvl(Sum(CASE 
                 WHEN ( DATE_ORDER BETWEEN SYSDATE - 10 AND SYSDATE ) THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END), 0) AS "0_10_DAYS", 
       Nvl(Sum(CASE 
                 WHEN ( DATE_ORDER BETWEEN SYSDATE - 20 AND SYSDATE - 11 ) THEN 
                 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END), 0) AS "10_20_DAYS", 
       Nvl(Sum(CASE 
                 WHEN ( DATE_ORDER BETWEEN SYSDATE - 30 AND SYSDATE - 21 ) THEN 
                 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END), 0) AS "20_30_DAYS", 
       Nvl(Sum(CASE 
                 WHEN ( DATE_ORDER <= To_date(SYSDATE - 30) ) THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END), 0) AS "PLUS_30_DAYS" 
FROM   
  types 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN T_ORDERS ON (types.t_name = T_ORDERS.TYPE ) 
WHERE 
  types.t_name IN ( 'X', 'Y','Z')
GROUP  BY types.t_name
```

Comment: Types arent in a type table. I have tried your first solution and it shows 1 in TOTAL when no data is retrieved for that type.

Comment: @user2629578: ok, i have edit my answer. i have adust the expression for the TOTAL column